# Apache2 + public_html Permissions

Tags: permissions, virtualhost, lamp, apache-2.2

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 10.10 Server w/ LAMP. I've created a new user account and added a public_html folder in their home directory. I installed and used Webmin to create a new VirtualHost and modified that host's DocumentRoot to /userfolder/public_html. In addition, I've properly symlinked the config file for that Vhost from sites-available to sites-enabled.

As of right now, I'm the only user on the server. If I want to add others (new user account, separate public_html directory), do I just repeat the process above? Or, are their security considerations?  What permissions do these directories need (chown useraccount, chgrp www-data, chmod 755)? Can I apply umask 022 automatically to all new files/folders?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several questions so I will address them in a list.

- Yes, repeating the process will work for additional users.
- For every directory in the structure above the `public_html` directory, the last bit in the mode must be set (`--------x`) (as well as any other bits) i.e., if `/home/joe/public_html` is the dir., `home` must have atleast `--------x` and `joe` must have atleast `--------x`
- `/blah/foo/bar/public_html` (and any subdirectories) must have atleast `------r-x`
- Files that should be web-accessible must be atleast `------r--`
- `umask 022` will create directories `rwxr-xr-x` and files `rw-r--r--` so this is fine

Some considerations:

- If you are changing the group to www-data, you can use group permissions instead of other/world permissions above.
- You don't need a vhost for every `public_html`, this just makes the URLs cleaner. If you don't create the vhost, the default way to access each user's site is `http://your.site.tld/~username` (This might still work even with vhosts. I've never actually used vhosts with users' `public_html`.